# csv file with NaN to empty with nothing inside

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Is there a way to change all the NaN to empty like this

I tried this:

```
data = pd.read_csv('iso_country_continent.csv', keep_default_na=False,  na_values=[' '])
```

current output:

```
 Unnamed: 0 geo_country        country continent
160         160          MX         Mexico       N_A
161         161          MY       Malaysia        AS
162         162          MZ     Mozambique        AF
163         163         Nan         Namibia        AF
164         164          NC  New Caledonia        OC
165         165          NE          Niger        AF
```

Expected output:

```
 Unnamed: 0 geo_country        country continent
160         160          MX         Mexico       N_A
161         161          MY       Malaysia        AS
162         162          MZ     Mozambique        AF
163         163                    Namibia        AF
164         164          NC  New Caledonia        OC
165         165          NE          Niger        AF
```

But i get the error like

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: If check values with `Na` in some editor, e.g. `notepad++` there are empty values? Or `Naan` ?

Answer (score 1):

If write `NaN`s values to file in pandas they are converted to empty strings.

So it seems your values are not missing values, but strings.

So need parameters `keep_default_na=False, na_values=['Naan']` for convert them to `NaN`s and then:

```
data = data.fillna('')
```

Or [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
data = pd.read_csv('iso_country_continent.csv')
data = data.replace({'Naan':''})
```

---

But if empty values in `csv` need parameter `keep_default_na=False` only, but no values are converted to `NaN`.

Or specify values to converting by `keep_default_na=False, na_values=['NaN']`

Comment: Thank you sir, I will try it